# $scope variable not reloaded

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, data-binding, angularjs-bindings

In the controller I have the code below :

```
//View
<input type="text" value="{{customer.lastName}}" />

//Controller
$scope.getbycode = function (customerCode) {
    var deferred = $q.defer(),
        getCustomerRequest = {
            code: customerCode
        };

    $http({ method: 'POST', url: 'api/customer/getbycode', data: getCustomerRequest })
        .success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function () {
            deferred.reject();
        });

    return deferred.promise;
};

$scope.getbycode($routeParams.customerCode).then(function (data) {
    $scope.customer = data.customer;
});
```

That's work, I see the lastname of Customer.

In the controller I have this code too. This function is called when I ckick on an hyperlink

```
$scope.reload = function (customerCode) {
    $scope.getbycode(customerCode).then(function (data) {
        $scope.customer = data.customer;
        alert($scope.customer.lastName);
    });
};
```

I change the text in the input and I click on the hyperlink.
The WEBAPI is called, the data returned in the `reload` function is correct but the view is not updated.

I missed something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value="{{customer.lastName}}"` will only evaluate expression first time & then it replaces with `customer.lastName` value which is `1`, DOM will look like below

```
<input type="text" value="1" />
```

Which had got rid off `{{customer.lastName}}` value, the changes in scope variable will never happen to that input field.

---

You should use `ng-model` there to have two way binding, that will update input & scope value once you update scope value.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="customer.lastName" />
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/XBJetjvXWoRs0dq4u0Fx?p=preview)